# Question about Fraïssé's theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory

In Bruno Poizat's book "A course in model theory" pages 35,36, he says :

> "we have no difficulty proving the first part of Fraïssé's theorem, that two $p$-equivalent tuples satisfy the same formulas of quantifier rank less than or equal to $p$".

He continues, "As the for converse, which depends on Lemma 2.3 ("there are only finitely many p-equivalence classes"), it is correct only if the signature can be reduced to a finite number of relations and and constants. In fact, one $single$ $function$ of nonzero arity allows the formation of infinitely many terms, and consequently infinltely many atomic formulas.

"Therefore, if we want to reduce elementary equivalence completely to finite back-and-forth criteria, we need to reduce it to finite signatures, and to replace each $n$-ary function by its graph, which is an $(n+1)$-ary relation. Doing this would preserve elementary equivalence, but change the notions of atomic formula, formula of quantifier rank $p$, $p-isomorphism$, etc."

I don't really understand what he says about functions here, about replacing them with their graphs. Can someone please explain why this is necessary? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is $p$-equivalence for tuples?

Comment: In the first chapter, the theorem is stated for a relation. He says two tuples in the universes of $R$ and $R'$ are $p-equivalent$ if they correspond via a $p-$isomorphism from $R$ to $R'$. This is an equivalence relation, and he writes  $(\overrightarrow{a},R)\sim_p (\overrightarrow{b},R')$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

**Theorem 2.2**, page 24 (Fraïssé's theorem) is stated for a *relation* $R$.

**Ch.3.2 Functions** (page 33-on) consider a language with also function symbols $f_j$.

The "trick" is to replace an $n$-ary function symbol $f$ with an $(n+1)$-ary *relation* symbol $R$.

Consider the simple example of arithmetic; the *sum* operation is a binary function : $+ : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.

Thus, we need a binary function symbol : $+(x,y)=z$.

We may replace it with a ternary relation symbol $+^*(x,y,z)$ defined as follows :

> $+^*(x,y,z)$ holds iff $z=+(x,y)$.

---

Compare with : [Graph of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) :

> in mathematics, the *graph of a function* $f$ is, formally, the set of all ordered pairs $(x, f(x))$, and, in practice, the graphical representation of this set.

In symbols : $\text {Graph}(f) = \{ (x, y) \mid y=f(x) \}$.

Comment: Okay, but I'm bothered when he says "single  function of nonzero arity allows the formation of infinitely many terms, and consequently infinltely many atomic formulas" and whether it would affect Lemma 2.3 "there are only finitely many p-equivalence classes"?

Comment: I understood it. Thank you. Just I was confused with "infinitely many atomic formulas", where the lemma says it should be finite